stand up comedy show in early 80s
In the early 80s, I remember watching a stand-up comedy special with several now-famous comedians and it was hilarious. It had Seinfeld, and Reiser as they were just starting out. I can't remember if I saw it on HBO or Showtime. 
Seinfeld did a bit about dogs riding in cars and Reiser did a bit about stupid people.
There was another blonde comedian whose name I can't remember, but he did a bit about the new ride at Disney World called 5 Blondes on a bed.
I would love to find a copy of this program.

HBO used to have a show called Dangerfield's or something.  It was Rodney Dangerfield's show, and he had several commedians on during each episode.  That was the first time I ever saw Jeff Foxworthy, Tim Allen and Andrew "Dice" Clay.  It's possible you saw an episode of that show.

I think it was On Location's annual Young Comedians Show. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Location_(TV_series)

Hmm...I tracked down Seinfeld's appearance to the 6th Annual Young Comedians Special (1981) but Reiser doesn't appear to have been on that special at all.
